# Max in an array of 6 numbers// It does not display the max

Tags: assembly, x86

I need the max of this array and it's position.In my opinion right now it should display the max of the array but it does not.
I would mainly need help and the loop that get the max and at another loop that right now I had not created that get position of the max, the final program should display the max mark and the number of the module.

```
 #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
int main(void){
char get1[] = "Enter the mark for module 1:";
char get2[] = "Enter the mark for module 2:";
char get3[] = "Enter the mark for module 3:";
char get4[] = "Enter the mark for module 4:";
char get5[] = "Enter the mark for module 5:";
char get6[] = "Enter the mark for module 6:";
char out1[] = "Best mark is ";
char out2[] = "for module";
char format[] = "%d"; // format string for the scanf function
int x;
int myarray[5];
int max = 0;
int module = 0;// declare variables in C
_asm {
    mov ebx, 0
    mov eax, x
    mov myarray[ebx], eax
        while1:lea eax, get1; 
        push eax
        call printf
        add esp, 4

        lea eax, x; 
        push eax
        lea eax, format
        push eax
        call scanf
        add esp, 8

        mov eax, x
        cmp eax, 0
        jl while1

        mov eax, x
        cmp eax, 100
        jg while1



        mov ebx, 1
        mov eax, x
        mov myarray[ebx], eax


        while2 : lea eax, get2; 
        push eax
        call printf
        add esp, 4

        lea eax, x; 
        push eax
        lea eax, format
        push eax
        call scanf
        add esp, 8

        mov eax, x
        cmp eax, 0
        jl while2
        mov eax, x
        cmp eax, 100
        jg while2



        mov ebx, 2
        mov eax, x
        mov myarray[ebx], eax

        while3 : lea eax, get3; 
        push eax
        call printf
        add esp, 4

        lea eax, x; 
        push eax
        lea eax, format
        push eax
        call scanf
        add esp, 8

        mov eax, x
        cmp eax, 0
        jl while3
        mov eax, x
        cmp eax, 100
        jg while3



        mov ebx, 3
        mov eax, x
        mov myarray[ebx], eax

        while4 : lea eax, get4; 
        push eax
        call printf
        add esp, 4

        lea eax, x; 
        push eax
        lea eax, format
        push eax
        call scanf
        add esp, 8

        mov eax, x
        cmp eax, 0
        jl while4
        mov eax, x
        cmp eax, 100
        jg while4



        mov ebx, 4
        mov eax, x
        mov myarray[ebx], eax

        while5 : lea eax, get5; // ask for the mark
        push eax
        call printf
        add esp, 4

        lea eax, x; 
        push eax
        lea eax, format
        push eax
        call scanf
        add esp, 8

        mov eax, x
        cmp eax, 0
        jl while5
        mov eax, x
        cmp eax, 100
        jg while5



        mov ebx, 5
        mov eax, x
        mov myarray[ebx], eax

        while6 : lea eax, get6; 
        push eax
        call printf
        add esp, 4

        lea eax, x; //read it in
        push eax
        lea eax, format
        push eax
        call scanf
        add esp, 8

        mov eax, x
        cmp eax, 0
        jl while6
        mov eax, x
        cmp eax, 100
        jg while6

            MOV ebx, 0
            MOV eax, myarray[ebx]
            MOV ecx, 5

            LAB1:CMP myarray[ebx], eax
            JAE PASS
            MOV eax, myarray[ebx]

            PASS : inc ebx
            dec ecx
            cmp ecx, 0
            jg LAB1
            MOV max, eax


            push max
            lea eax, out1
            push eax
            call printf
            add esp, 8
```

Comment: Comment your code, especially if you want others to help. Also, learn to use a debugger so you can fix your own mistakes.

Comment: This is not a [mcve] (too long, no clear description of what it does and how it's supposed to work vs. what it actually does and what you see with a debugger).  See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int myarray[5];
> ```

This defines an array containing 6 **dwords**.
Because you don't seem to understand what an instruction like `mov myarray[ebx], eax` really does, all of your assignments to the array overlap. The `[ebx]` part is actually an offset in the array. **It is not an index like the one's found in high level languages**. What you need then is scaling like:

```
mov myarray[ebx*4], eax
```

---

> ```
> LAB1:CMP myarray[ebx], eax
>      JAE PASS
>      MOV eax, myarray[ebx]
> ```

This code really does the opposite of what you want. If an array element is smaller than the `EAX` register, you put it in the `EAX` register. This way the `EAX` register gets smaller and smaller. Later on you will display this as the *maximum* where in fact (if the rest of the code were correct) it would be the *minimum*.

---

Why do you input 6 numbers?

- The 1st array element is filled from a variable *x*
- The 2nd array element is filled using the 1st input
- The 3rd array element is filled using the 2nd input
- The 4th array element is filled using the 3rd input
- The 5th array element is filled using the 4th input
- The 6th array element is filled using the 5th input

**The 6th input goes nowhere!**